# WinAPI LB_GETCURSEL always return 1

Tags: winapi, listbox

I have a dialog box that has a ListBox element. Whatever I choose in it, LB_GETCURSEL always returns 1, even if there is only 1 item in the list. Below is the code for processing dialog box messages.

USELESS!. The site doesn't allow me to post my question because it has a lot of code and few words, so I added this part

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK SetDLG(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    
    int k=0;
    HWND List = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_ORIENTATION);
    switch (msg)
    {
        
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        
        SendMessage(List, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)(LPSTR)"Vertically");
        SendMessage(List, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)(LPSTR)"Horizontally");
        

        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_Text, str.TEXT);

        _itoa_s(str.TextColor, tempText, 10);
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_TextCode, tempText);

        _itoa_s(str.BGColor, tempText, 10);
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_BGCode, tempText);

        if (str.orientation == 0) //Horizontally
        {
            SendMessage(List, LB_SETCURSEL, 1, 0L);
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(List, LB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0L);
        }

        return TRUE;
    };

        

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        
        case IDOK:
            {
                GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_Text, str.TEXT, 1024);

                GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_TextCode, tempText, 10);
                str.TextColor = atoi(tempText);

                GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_BGCode, tempText, 10);
                str.BGColor = atoi(tempText);

                
                if (k = SendMessage(List, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L) != LB_ERR)
                {
                    SendMessage(List, LB_GETTEXT, k, (LPARAM)tempText);
                }

                if (!strcmp(tempText, "Horizontally") )
                    str.orientation = 0;
                else if(!strcmp(tempText, "Vertically"))
                    str.orientation = 1;

                EndDialog(hDlg, IDOK);
                return TRUE;
            };
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> WinAPI LB_GETCURSEL always return 1

No, it doesn't. As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-getcursel)

> the return value is the zero-based index of the currently selected item. If there is no selection, the return value is LB_ERR.

There is no immediate reason to question whether this is correct. You can safely assume that it is. The issue is rather in your code, specifically this:

```cpp
if (k = SendMessage(List, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L) != LB_ERR)
```

Presumably, what you *meant* to write was this:

```cpp
if ((k = SendMessage(List, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L)) != LB_ERR)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ evaluate this first
```

But C++' [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) turns it into this instead:

```cpp
if (k = (SendMessage(List, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L) != LB_ERR))
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Oops
```

with the second expression evaluating to `false` when there is no selection, and `true` when there is. The `bool` gets then promoted to an `int` with a value of `0` or `1`. Since the code makes sure that there always is a selection, you'll always observe `k` as having value `1`.

Using parentheses as in the second code snippet fixes the immediate issue. Optimizing for readability would have solved this issue before it ever happened, by moving the assignment out of the `if` clause. Just saying, you know...